# Reg: Query change in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle and learning the course and encountered some blockers. I have the below query where the ddetl table is slowing down the query due to the inner query logic which is written. I was wondering if there is any way I can make change so that I do not use the **OR ** condition when picking the ddetl record.

I could only think of making the query as dynamic query but I don't think it is an efficient idea. Could you please advise on how I should proceed? (Not expecting the query to be written for me, but just want an idea).

```
SELECT 1,
       rcd.id,
       sr.id ,
       rcd.crit_seq,
       rcd.ev_id,
       null,
       dd.funds_avail_date,
       sr.action_allowed,
       dd.dsba_id,
       decode(sr.detl_level,'Y',dd.seqnbr,null),
       dd.ga_id
  FROM rc_detail   rcd,
       ddetl       dd,
       sr_crit     src,
       srule       sr,
       sr_type     rt
 WHERE rt.id = sr.rule_type
   and sr.id = rcd.std_rl_id
   and src.std_rl_id = sr.id
   and rcd.std_rl_id = src.std_rl_id
   and rcd.crit_seq = src.seqnbr
   and src.crit_type = 'STD'
   and ((nvl(sr.detl_level,'N') != 'Y'
          and (dd.dsba_id,dd.ga_id,dd.seqnbr) in
              (SELECT MIN(dsba_id),MIN(ga_id), MIN(seqnbr)
                  FROM   ddetl
                 WHERE  dsba_id = v_dsba_id
                   AND  ga_id = v_ga_id))
           OR (sr.detl_level = 'Y'
               and dd.dsba_id = v_dsba_id
               and dd.ga_id = v_ga_id))
 and rt.id = 'LOAN-SPEC'
 and nvl(rcd.irs_code,'xxxxx') = 'xxxxx'
 and nvl(rcd.dsrs_code,'xxxxx') = 'xxxxx'
 and nvl(rcd.dsmd_code,'xxxxx') = 'xxxxx'
 and nvl(rcd.sdio_id,dd.sdio_id) = dd.sdio_id
 and nvl(rcd.sdmt_code,dd.sdmt_code) = dd.sdmt_code
 and (nvl(rcd.gaio_qual,dd.gaio_qual) = dd.gaio_qual OR
         dd.gaio_qual is null)
 and (nvl(rcd.gdmt_seqnbr,dd.gdmt_seqnbr) = dd.gdmt_seqnbr OR
         dd.gdmt_seqnbr is null);
```

I tried to make changes using "with as" query but it did't work or I was not able to make the change so that the query could work.

Below is the logic I would like to change.

```
   and ((nvl(sr.detl_level,'N') != 'Y'
          and (dd.dsba_id,dd.ga_id,dd.seqnbr) in
              (SELECT MIN(dsba_id),MIN(ga_id), MIN(seqnbr)
                 FROM   ddetl
                WHERE  dsba_id = v_dsba_id
                  AND  ga_id = v_ga_id))
            OR (sr.detl_level = 'Y'
               and dd.dsba_id = v_dsba_id
               and dd.ga_id = v_ga_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

As to a person who is new to Oracle I would advise you to read some more documentation about basic rules for selections and joining tables. You are using join sintax that was out of use for 30 years. Try to give aliases to your selected columns not to end up with "column ambiguosly defined" error.
Sorry, but it is almost impossible to help with your code without some sample data and with no expected result. I tried to rewrite it to look like it could work. I did it blindly and it will not work but maybe you could get some idea how to make it work with your actual data. However, there are two identifiers of unknown origin in your code that I couldn't figure out what to do with (v_dsba_id and v_ga_id).
Here is the code (with some more comments) that could help you find your way out of the mess:

```sql
Select      1 "SOME_NUMBER_COLUMN",     --  all columns now have aliases
            rcd.id "RCD_ID",
            sr.id "SR_ID",
            rcd.crit_seq "CRIT_SEQ",
            rcd.ev_id "EV_ID",
            Null "SOME_NULL_COLUMN",
            dd.funds_avail_date "FUNDS_DATE",
            sr.action_allowed "ACTION_ALLOWED",
            dd.dsba_id "DSBA_ID",
            Decode(sr.detl_level, 'Y', dd.seqnbr, Null) "DETL_LEVEL_OR_SEQNBR",
            dd.ga_id "GA_ID"
From        rc_detail rcd                       -- tables Inner or Left joind by ON() conditions
--
Inner Join  sr_crit src ON  (   src.std_rl_id = rcd.std_rl_id And 
                                src.seqnbr = rcd.crit_seq And
                                src.crit_type = 'STD'       )  -- nothing selected from sr_crit - could be a filter ('STD')
--
Inner Join  srule sr ON( sr.id = rcd.std_rl_id )
--
Inner Join  sr_type rt ON(rt.id = sr.rule_type And rt.id = 'LOAN-SPEC') -- nothing selected from sr_type - could be a filter ('LOAN-SPEC')
--
Inner Join  ddetl dd ON (   dd.sdio_id = Nvl(rcd.sdio_id, dd.sdio_id) And 
                            dd.sdmt_code = Nvl(rcd.sdmt_code, dd.sdmt_code) And 
                            (   dd.gaio_qual = Nvl(rcd.gaio_qual, dd.gaio_qual) OR dd.gaio_qual is null ) And 
                            (   dd.gdmt_seqnbr = Nvl(rcd.gdmt_seqnbr, dd.gdmt_seqnbr) OR dd.gdmt_seqnbr is null ) 
                        )
--
Left Join   (   Select  MIN(dsba_id) "MIN_DSBA_ID", 
                        MIN(ga_id) "MIN_GA_ID", 
                        MIN(seqnbr) "MIN_SEQNBR" 
                From    ddetl 
                Where   dsba_id = v_dsba_id And     --  WHAT is v_dsba_id 
                        ga_id = v_ga_id             --  WHAT is v_ga_id
            ) dd2 ON(   dd2.MIN_DSBA_ID = dd.dsba_id And 
                        dd2.MIN_GA_ID = dd.ga_id And 
                        dd2.MIN_SEQNBR = dd.seqnbr And   
                    )
Where   COALESCE(rcd.irs_code, rcd.dsrs_code, rcd.dsmd_code) Is Null And    -- COALESCE() function instead of tripple Nulls converted to 'xxxx'
        (   
            ( dd2.MIN_DSBA_ID Is Not Null And Nvl(sr.detl_level, 'N') != 'Y' )
          OR
            ( dd.dsba_id = v_dsba_id And dd.ga_id = v_ga_id And sr.detl_level = 'Y' )   --  WHAT are v_dsba_id and v_ga_id
        )
```

Once again, this is just a blind try to guess what is realy happening - this code will not work without your intervention...

Comment: So the join syntax being outdated doesnt have impact on the performance. I was able to use the explain plan and get the issue. Thanks anyways.